# will <error-page> catch java.lang.throwable exception in servlet 3.0+ app?

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-3.0

I have a web application with servlet 3.0.
For default error pages in the application I have done following in web config.

```
<error-page>
  <location>error.html> </location>
<error-page>
```

Will this also catch Java.lang.Throwable exception or do I need to define error page for them seperately with  ?

Any links to official documentation will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to [tutorialspoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/servlets-exception-handling.htm)

> If you want to have a generic Error Handler for all the exceptions then you should define following error-page instead of defining separate error-page elements for every exception:

```
<error-page>
   <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type >
<location>/ErrorHandler</location>
```

Comment: Hi. This will for following type of exceptions 
    
'javax.servlet.ServletException'
 'java.io.IOException'
 and not http error codes. My question is will just defining  <error-page> in servlet 3.0 catch run time exceptions ?

Comment: @Hardik HTTP error codes are not exceptions, and exceptions are handled by this answer.

Comment: @Kayaman, So do I need HTTP error handler and Exception handler defined separately in web config ?